# Why is WPF/XAML adding 3 "Mocks" objects to my IEnumerable collection in my ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, design-time

I have a property defined in my ViewModel as such:

```
public IEnumerable<SubsystemFilterState> CurrentFilterStates { get; private set; }
```

That I want to display in my view. I've done the binding to a `Label` and provided a converter:

XAML:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource LabelFilterIndicator}"
       Content="{Binding CurrentFilterStates, 
                 Converter={StaticResource FilterConverter}, 
                 Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Converter:

```
public class FilterIndicatorConverter
    : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        try
        {
            var indicator = "No Filter Selected";

            if (value != null)
            {                    
                IEnumerable<SubsystemFilterState> states = (IEnumerable<SubsystemFilterState>)value;
                indicator = states.Count() > 1
                            ?
                            "Multiple Systems"
                            :
                            states.First().Acronym.ToString();

            }
            return indicator;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works fine at run-time. At design-time, it's throwing an exception which is displayed in my label. Here's the exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Mocks.Models_SubsystemFilterState_14_1174211]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.SubsystemFilterState]'.

I can't figure out where this magical `ObservableCollection` is coming from. I don't have a `Mocks` namespace and have never mocked any value into that property. I changed the code in my converter to the following, to find out where they're coming from:

Quick and/or dirty:

```
public class FilterIndicatorConverter
    : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        try
        {
            var indicator = "";

            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach (dynamic test in value as IEnumerable)
                {

                    Type type = test.GetType();
                    indicator += string.Format("Start{0}" +
                                               "AssemblyQualifiedName: {0}{6}{1}{0}" +
                                               "Namespace: {0}{6}{2}{0}" +
                                               "Assembly: {0}{6}{3}{0}" +
                                               "BaseType: {0}{6}{4}{0}" +
                                               "FullName: {0}{6}{5}{0}{0}",
                                               "\n",
                                               type.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                                               type.Namespace,
                                               type.Assembly,
                                               type.BaseType,
                                               type.FullName,
                                               "  ");

                }

            }
            return indicator;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which displays this:

[image: Error]

It looks like Visual Studio is adding these in at design time but why does it not match the type of my property? Can I turn this off? What is the `DesignTools` namespace?

Comment: Did you build this XAML originally in VS or did you use Blend?  In my experience, Blend can add these sorts of things.  As such, I've abandoned using it.

Comment: Do you have any design namespace or attributes in the window/usercontrol (the root of the XAML)?

Comment: No, this was all built with Visual Studio. Now, I do have namespace stuff in my XAML and one of them **is** the blend namespace, but it was added automatically with creating a new project, so I left it there. I'm new to WPF so I don't know what, if any, namespaces could affect this.

Comment: well, what do you expect `CurrentFilterStates` to evaluate to during design time? How do you tell your View about the ViewModel? The VS WPF Designer is not executing all of your code during design time, so I'd not be too concerned if it wrapped some of my types to just be able to do anything.

Comment: @MarkusHütter I guess I'd expect it to evaluate to the same type that the property is. I'm using Prism and `AutoWireViewModel`. I'm okay with it wrapping my types but isn't the point of a converter to make complex types displayable? I ended up putting in some code to check specifically for a value that my converter should never receive. I don't mind doing it once, but for every converter to account for (IMO) a bug in Blend/VS will bloat my code unnecessarily.

Comment: @Brandon Did you find a solution for this behavior? I'm experiencing the same problem. It's very annoying that I'm not able to see the view in the designer anymore because of this bug.

Comment: @RamNow I didn't end up finding a solution other than to put design-time code in there, as per my comment above yours.